How can I add an external antenna to a GooSKY S1 mini helicopter flight controller?
I recently purchased the GooSKY S1 mini helicopter flight controller with a receiver that has an internal antenna, as shown in the picture below:

I have limited knowledge of RF and I’m unsure whether adding an external antenna would improve the range. I’ve come across some sources suggesting that it could, but I want to be sure before making any modifications.
Is there a recommended method for adding an external antenna, other than simply soldering a wire to the existing antenna or to any exposed pads on the PCB? Would such a modification potentially improve performance, or is there a better approach to achieve a more stable and longer-range signal?

On this site it is fine to ask questions on the design level, such as questions about RF theory or band use, modifying or redesigning existing documented designs, component identification questions etc. But it is not ok to ask questions on the product level such as how does undocumented product x work or how do I modify it. So in order to ask this question here, you need to clarify what frequency band this is using and a simple schematic about the RF rx path including where/how the current PCB antenna is connected etc. (On the pic it ends in something like not mounted zero ohm resistor?)

For product-level questions, you should ask at https://drones.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Improving the range often will be illegal in most countries.

The people who designed the RF module will have done the best job they can within the constraints of the size and placement.  Unless you know what you’re doing and have access to the right equipment, it’s highly unlikely that any changes you make will improve the performance.  If you found and antenna with better performance (depending on what you want to do with it, I’d assume you’d want reasonably isotropic behaviour for a UAV) you’d need to re-tune the circuit to match the new configuration; this calls for a vector network analyser and some experimentation.  That’s not to say that you couldn’t do it but it would require a significant investment in equipment and learning.

These kind of square-shaped PCB antenna from some 2.4GHz hobby kit are not necessarily the "best job" but just mindlessly copied from some other hobby kit. It is not far-fetched to assume that an external antenna will do better. For example how is the antenna located in relation to nearby metal parts. However, using a different antenna than the one used during EMC testing would also make the product illegal...
